# Full image not coming using imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image of dimension 4096 X 2304. I can view that Image when double click. 
Then i wanted to write my own opencv (ver 2.4.3) program to display this image.  But The image is not fitting on the screen. It is showing only 50%, rest of the part is cutting.

This my code for image display:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        Mat im = imread("1.jpg");
        if (im.empty()) 
        {
            cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        imshow("Image", im);
        waitKey(0);
    }
```

The screen resolution of my monitor is 1366 x 768 maximum.

So why my program is unable to display the full uncut image?

Comment: Your displayed image is bigger than your scteen, that's why you cant display it ;)

Comment: Try cv::namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); before imshow and resize ;)

Comment: I meant named window with WINDOW_NORMAL parameter... not autosize

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have done partial editing of your code, just the gutsy bits 0_0 ):

```
Mat im_s = imread("myimg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (im_s.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

namedWindow( "Myimg", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

Size size(4096,2304);
Mat im;
resize(im_s, im, size);

imshow("Myimg", im);

waitkey(0);

return 0;
```

Comment: this does not work. I think I need to resize it also.

Comment: thanks for the update, but resize does not work.   Error 1 error C3861: 'resize': identifier not found. (my opencv ver is 2.4.3)

Comment: @TabishSaifullah      did you have `#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>` in the file?

Comment: If I try to use cvResize , then this error comes: Error 1 error C2664: 'cvResize' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvArr *'

Comment: I think my Opencv ver is an older version , and  cvResize is expecting  CvArr instead of Mat. But is there a way to convert it ?

Comment: @TabishSaifullah      If you have cv::Mat why do you still insist using old openCV CvMat type? add the header I mentioned in the comment and see if that works.